# Re-allocate space to /usr

Tags: filesystem

Pardon my newbee-ness, but when I look at my file system with df -h, I see how most of my space is in /dev/sda1.  I'd like to add space to /usr, to install hadoop.  I am confused about how to re-allocate that space, or if  I even need to.  Can someone clear up my understanding?  Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you [edit] your post to include the output of `df`? That should make it possible to answer your question accurately.

Comment: And the output of `lsblk` as well.

Answer (score 0):

/dev/sda1 is your actual hard drive and that's why it seems to have all of the space. The space you need should be dynamically allocated to /usr and available to hadoop when you install it.

Answer (score 0):

If you use `lsblk` as shown here:

```
$ lsblk
NAME   MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda      8:0    0 232,9G  0 disk 
├─sda1   8:1    0   487M  0 part /boot/efi
├─sda2   8:2    0 200,5G  0 part /
└─sda3   8:3    0    32G  0 part [SWAP]
sdb      8:176  1   7,5G  0 disk 
└─sdb1   8:177  1   7,5G  0 part /media/hannu/PHONE_CARD
sr0     11:0    1  1024M  0 rom
```

you see the contents from partition tables on sda and sdb

`sda` is the first harddisk.

`sda1` - the first partition on `sda` as it has /boot/efi last on the same line, I can tell that this is where my boot data resides. The content tells which kernel to use, what partition to start reading, how to use it and additionally also holds the actual kernel.

`sda2` with a `/` last on the line, this is the root file system of my Linux installation. `ls -l /` will show the upper level of the contents.

`sda3` - and `[SWAP]` last on the line - this partition corresponds to the swapfile of Windows machines.

`sdb` is an USB-memnory stick, here with the ability to mount a microSD card which has one partition; `sdb1`. The content at this time is readable at `/media/hannu/PHONE_CARD/`

`sr0` is the empty CD/DVD RW device.

Answer (score 0):

`/dev/sda1` is a partition, and from what you say ("most of my space is in /dev/sda1"), I think this is the partition you used for Ubuntu's root (`/`). Since you are a newbie, I think it is unlikely that you assigned a separate partition for `/usr`, so `/usr` is using the same space as everything else (the space in `/dev/sda1`). So you don't need to reassign any space.